# Is it possible to use an external font in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, fonts, jetbrains-font

I want to change the font in Eclipse IDE (to [JetBrains Mono](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/)).

Here is what I tried:
Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Java > Java Editor Text Font > Edit... > Show more fonts

However, this just brings you to the Windows font settings, rather than actually allowing you to import a font. It seems as if the "Show more fonts" link (see below) is redundant.

Is there a workaround?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Fonts are made available to apps such as your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) (Eclipse) through the host operating system.

1. Install the font into the host OS. Download the font zip from the page you linked, unzip the file, right-click on the `.ttf` you intended to use, and pick the option to **Install**.
2. Restart your IDE, or perhaps your computer, if necessary.
3. Choose your desired font in the settings of your IDE.

For more info:

- [*Install and validate fonts in Font Book on Mac*](https://support.apple.com/guide/font-book/install-and-validate-fonts-fntbk1000/mac)
- [*How to Install Fonts in Windows 11*](https://www.lifewire.com/install-fonts-in-windows-11-5192443)
- [*How to install and manage fonts on Linux*](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-and-manage-fonts-on-linux)

See also [the instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/#how-to-install) for your desired font, *JetBrains Mono*.